# Change selection color on Button's and TextView's in Android

Tags: java, android, themes, selection

I'm developing an app and when I run it in the Emulator and I've selected a button (not clicked!) it shows an orange layer over it. When i click it i turns yellow.
On a HTC device the orange/yellow overlay is green. On a Samsung Galaxy S it's blue.

I want my app to have the same selection color's throughout the whole app (Blue to be precise).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think link provided below could be helpful for you

link is: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/a7ff938ce09e7c37

Comment: Thanks for the link, but they change the whole button with different drawable's. I just want to change the color of the Selector

Comment: But you can change your selector as required by you

Comment: You can use any color as required by you and also set on focus only as there is need of yours here in this code <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/some_png" /> <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/some_png" /> <item android:drawable="@drawable/other_bg" /> </selector>

Comment: but i don't want to load a png, but just change the default phone-chosen color to a standard blue.

Comment: just try using "#<code of blue here>" instead of  "@drawable/some_png"

Comment: It says Color types not allowed at 'drawable'

Comment: I got it working by the example Labeeb provided, but I thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Use [Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) to apply style to the whole app.

Comment: I've read through the whole page, but I can't understand it. I'm quite new to Android. I think I have to work with Selector or something?

Answer (score 0):

You r right

But u also set background color at runtime

& Another

possibility that  may be HTC /Samsung has different Android Version ?

so this Happen

Answer (score 0):

Create a selector in your drawable folder
for example drawable/item_selctor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_button_selected"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_button_selected"
          android:state_focused="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_button_selected"
          android:state_selected="true" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_button" />
     </selector>
```

In your code or xml file use

```
 item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_selector);
```

in code
or

```
android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
```

in xml layout file